Secure alternatives to -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no in SSH for Jenkins pipeline
I am currently learning about CI/CD and have set up a dummy Jenkins pipeline for educational purposes. In my pipeline, I am using the -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no flag in the SSH commands to disable strict host key checking and allow automatic addition of the server's public key to the known_hosts file. However, I am aware that this approach poses security risks as it bypasses the verification of the server's identity and can make the connection vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.
I would like to find alternative methods to establish a secure SSH connection without using the -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no flag. My goal is to ensure that the server's identity is properly verified while still allowing for a smooth and automated connection process.
Here's some additional context about my setup:

I have two EC2 instances: one running Jenkins and the other serving as the deployment server.
The Jenkins pipeline builds a Docker image and deploys it to the deployment server.
The EC2 instances do not have static IP addresses or Elastic IPs, as they are used for demo purposes.
I am using the sshagent plugin in Jenkins to manage the SSH key for connecting to the deployment server.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my Jenkinsfile:
stage("Deploy") {
  steps {
    script {
      echo 'Deploying the Docker image to the deployment server...'
      def shellCmd = "bash ./server-commands.sh ${IMAGE_NAME}"
      def deploymentServer = "ec2-user@<deployment-server-public-ip>"

      sshagent(['my-ssh-key']) {
        sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server-commands.sh ${deploymentServer}:/home/ec2-user"
        sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no docker-compose.yaml ${deploymentServer}:/home/ec2-user"
        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${deploymentServer} ${shellCmd}"
      }
    }
  }
}

Can anyone provide guidance on the best practices for securely managing SSH host key checking in a Jenkins pipeline, considering the dynamic nature of the EC2 instances? Are there any recommended techniques or tools that can help verify the server's identity without compromising security?
I understand that using -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no is not ideal, especially in a production environment. However, since this is a learning setup, I am open to exploring secure alternatives that can be applied in real-world scenarios.
Any insights, examples, or resources related to this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Two questions: 1. How do you pass deployment-server-public-ip to the pipeline? 2. Is the EC2 instance you are deploying to long lived (you are going to connect multiple times to the same instance), or do you spin up a new EC2 instance for each deployment?

Hi @Iterokun sorry for the delayed response. To answer your first question, I am saving the SSH credentials for the EC2 instance in Jenkins. To answer your second question, I am not spinning up a new EC2 instance every time I run the pipeline. Please also note that, I am a student who is currently learning DevOps.

Where do you save the IP of instance? It's relevant, because you probably want to save the host key fingerprint somewhere close.
